# Difference between "which" and ", which"?

Tags: commas

Is there a difference between the following two sentences?

> She read the document which upset me.
>
> She read the document, which upset me.

Answer (score 1):

She read the document which upset me - suggests that the document included something that upset you. In this case, I would use "She read the document that upset me" because "that" is a restrictive word, which means that it provides essential information about the noun "document" and is used without a comma.

She read the document, which upset me - suggests that the fact that she read the document upset you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with MihaelaP

In terms of grammar:

*She read the document which upset me*. ('which upset me' is adjectival to 'document')

*She read the document, which upset me.*  (', which upset me' is adverbial to 'read')

---

Note that American English makes a greater distinction between 'that' and 'which' than British English.

Comment: I wouldn't say that "which upset me" in the second example is adverbial, since that implies that it modifies the verb, which it doesn't. Supplementary (non-defining) relatives are not modifiers. Instead they have a semantic 'anchor' that they refer you. In this case the anchor is the whole main clause "she read the document". We understand her reading the document upset you.